# Update Value in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, subtraction

Good Day Guys. Im creating sql syntax which subtract the current value of `ContractQty` to `TotalAmountQty`. 
The code Below subtract `ContractQty` and `TotalAmountQty` in Temporary Table. My Question is how can I update the value of `ContractQty` to my Table Retail. `XDeal` ColumnName `ContractQty` where `DocNumber`. getting the data from Temporary Table? The value in the screen shoot need to get and update my column `ContractQty` in `Retail.XDeal` Thanks Regards

```
    WITH A AS (SELECT A.DocNumber,SUM(B.Qty) AS TotalAmountQty 
    FROM Retail.XDeal A
    INNER JOIN Retail.XDealDetail B
    ON A.DocNumber = B.DocNumber
    GROUP BY A.DocNumber)

    SELECT SUM(A.ContractQty-B.TotalAmountQty) as ContractQty FROM Retail.XDeal A
    INNER JOIN A B
    ON A.DocNumber = B.DocNumber
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very confusing question. If you could, ask someone with a better command of written English to review your question and suggest appropriate edits. This sentence in particular is very hard to understand: "My Question is how can I update the value of ContractQty to my Table Retail.XDeal ColumnName ContractQty where DocNumber. getting the data from Temporary Table?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do; this should work:

```
SELECT DocNumber, SUM(Qty) AS TotalAmountQty 
INTO #temp
FROM Retail.XDealDetail
GROUP BY DocNumber

UPDATE Retail.XDeal
SET ContractQty = A.ContractQty - B.TotalAmountQty
FROM    Retail.XDeal A
        JOIN #temp B ON A.DocNumber = B.DocNumber;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: [Gordon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23692032/173497) is 'cleaner', and it's more similar to your example code, so I would strongly suggest that you make an effort to understand how the code in it works. The reason why I wrote the code in my answer as I did is that you explicitly mentioned a "temporary table", even tho your example code didn't include one. What you might be thinking of as a 'temporary table' (which isn't really wrong actually!) – i.e. the `WITH ... ( ... )` part – is called a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can do an `update` with a `join` in SQL Server.  This is the syntax:

```
WITH A AS (
      SELECT xd.DocNumber, SUM(xdd.Qty) AS TotalAmountQty 
      FROM Retail.XDeal xd INNER JOIN
           Retail.XDealDetail xdd
           ON xd.DocNumber = xdd.DocNumber
      GROUP BY xd.DocNumber
    )
UPDATE xd
    SET ContractQty = A.TotalAmountQty
    FROM Retail.XDetail xd JOIN
         A
         ON xd.DocNumber = A.DocNumber;
```

The `join` for `A` is unnecessary, so this is a simpler version:

```
WITH A AS (
      SELECT xdd.DocNumber, SUM(xdd.Qty) AS TotalAmountQty 
      FROM Retail.XDealDetail xdd
      GROUP BY xdd.DocNumber
    )
UPDATE xd
    SET ContractQty = A.TotalAmountQty
    FROM Retail.XDetail xd JOIN
         A
         ON xd.DocNumber = A.DocNumber;
```

Personally, I would make the CTE a subquery, but that is just a matter of preference.

Comment: Sir where is code for subtraction of two Column. My code below already  subtract and save to temporary column . I need to get the value of ContractQty and update to my Table.

Comment: @Renats . . . The question is:  "how can I update the value of ContractQty to my Table Retail.XDeal ColumnName ContractQty where DocNumber. getting the data from Temporary Table".  Where does the subtraction come in?  If you want to subtract the total from the existing, just use `set ContractQty = ContracdtQty - TotalAmountQty`.

Comment: okay sir. when i compress my code with one sp i got this error sir
'A' is not a recognized GROUP BY option

Comment: @Renats . . . I changed the alias of the `A` table to `xd` in the subquery.  Table abbreviations make much better aliases than arbitrary letters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention version of sql-server, but recent versions support `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO Retail.XDeal xd2
USING (
    SELECT xd.DocNumber, SUM(xdd.Qty) AS TotalAmountQty 
    FROM Retail.XDeal xd
    JOIN Retail.XDealDetail xdd
        ON xd.DocNumber = xdd.DocNumber
    GROUP BY xd.DocNumber
) y
    ON xd2.DocNumber = y.DocNumber
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET xd2.ContractQty = y.TotalAmountQty
```

As I did not fully understand your scenario, this probably does not do what you want, but it should give you an idea on how to use `MERGE`